# redirección subdirectorio con htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Buenos dias tengo un wordpress instalado en https://www.miweb.com/nuevaweb.

Quiero conseguir que www.miweb.com/nuevaweb sea la base del dominio. Es decir, desde fuera se verá solo www.miweb.com.

Por ahora he hecho este htaccess que me funciona a medias:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?miweb.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nuevaweb/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nuevaweb/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?miweb.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ nuevaweb/index.php [L]
```

Con esta configuración lo hace bien siempre y cuando entre via https. Pero si se accede con http://miweb.com me està redirigiendo a http://miweb.com/nuevaweb y me salta un error de wordpress 404 ya que es como si intentara cargar http://miweb.com/nuevaweb/nuevaweb.

Que se me escapa?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Estoy viendo que para la misma condición "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?miweb.com$ " ¿Hay dos reglas distintas, puede que se esté haciendo un lío? Intenta borrando las dos líneas de abajo y pueba.

Comment: Yo preguntaría ¿por qué quieres hacer eso? ¿Por qué no migras tu Wordpress al directorio `public_html` de `miweb.com`. Tu planteamiento no es atractivo a nivel de SEO, ni tampoco a nivel de la experiencia de usuario... a no ser que lo que quieras sea tener dos webs distintas funcionando en el mismo dominio. Sería lo único que justificaría lo que estás intentando hacer y en ese caso, deberías darle un nombre más *profesional* a la carpeta `nuevaweb` (por ejemplo `app`, o `info` ... ) para poder acceder a ella así: `app.miweb.com` o así `info.miweb.com`
.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El nombre "nuevaweb" lo he puesto aqui a modo de ejemplo únicamente. En efecto tengo 2 sitios web en el mismo dominio, una es la web corporativa y la otra la zona cliente. Las tengo separado con 2 instalaciones de wordpress diferentes por motivos de funcionalidad y con la siguiente estructura a nivel de carpetas:
/html/zonacliente  y /html/webcorporativa

A la web corporativa se accede mediante https://miweb.com y a la zona cliente mediante https://miweb.com/zonacliente. Con la zona cliente no tengo ningun problema en entrar ya sea mediante http o https.

Comment: Con la web corporativa cuando entro via https carga correctamente "https://miweb.com" pero si no pongo el https i entro via http se me carga http://miweb.com/webcorporativa y por tanto me da error 404.

Es lo que estoy intentando corregir, que con esa misma configuración el http me redirija a la versión https y así cargue bien.

Comment: **He resuelto el problema editando la pagina 404 de wordpress para que me redirija a la versión https.**